# Correct syntax using a foreach with a click function in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to create an array in order to use multiple unique IDs. I thought I would need to use a foreach (or maybe just each()) statement to make this code work, but it still doesn't. I've tried both. Is my syntax wrong, or am I using the wrong method to make this work. The if statements are working fine using single var objects. I hope I'm stating this clearly, I am new to jQuery. I should also mention, this is for a bunch of Wordpress custom meta box fields. Also, this works fine if BTNID and TXTID are single object vars.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var btnid = new Array( '#mybuttonid1', '#mybuttonid2', 'mybuttonid3', 'mybuttonid4' );

    // Instantiates the variable that holds the media library frame.
    var meta_image_frame;

    // Runs when the image button ID clicked.
    $.each( btnid ).click(function(e) {

        // Prevents the default action from occuring. 
        e.preventDefault();

        // If the frame already exists, re-open it.
        if ( meta_image_frame ) {
            meta_image_frame.open();
            return;
        }

        // Sets up the media library frame
        meta_image_frame = wp.media.frames.meta_image_frame = wp.media({
            title: meta_image.title,
            button: { text:  meta_image.button },
            library: { type: 'image' }
        });

        // Runs when an image is selected.
        meta_image_frame.on('select', function(){

            if ( btnid == ‘#mybuttonid1') {
                var txtid = '#mytextid1’;
            } else if ( btnid == '#mybuttonid2') {
                var txtid = '#mytextid2’;
            } else if ( btnid == '#mybuttonid3') {
                var txtid = '#mytextid3’;
            } else {
                var txtid = '#htxmltiimgupdtlw';
            }

            // Grabs the attachment selection and creates a JSON representation of the model.
            var media_attachment = meta_image_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();

            // Sends the attachment URL to our custom image input field.
            $( txtid ).val(media_attachment.url);
        });

        // Opens the media library frame.
        meta_image_frame.open();
    });
});
```

Comment: Notice the wonky syntax highlighting?  You've got a funky quote character . . . :-).

Comment: Yes @mgilson I noticed, thanks. But that's not the problem, that just comes from copying and pasting from my text editor. Those odd characters are not on my php files. I wish the problem were that simple. But thanks again for letting me know, this is my first time using the site.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var btnid = new Array( '#mybuttonid1', '#mybuttonid2', 'mybuttonid3', 'mybuttonid4' );

    // Instantiates the variable that holds the media library frame.
    var meta_image_frame;

    // Runs when the image button ID clicked.
    $.each( btnid, function(){
      $(this).click(function(e) {
        // Prevents the default action from occuring. 
        e.preventDefault();

        // If the frame already exists, re-open it.
        if ( meta_image_frame ) {
            meta_image_frame.open();
            return;
        }

        // Sets up the media library frame
        meta_image_frame = wp.media.frames.meta_image_frame = wp.media({
            title: meta_image.title,
            button: { text:  meta_image.button },
            library: { type: 'image' }
        });

        // Runs when an image is selected.
        meta_image_frame.on('select', function(){

            if ( btnid == ‘#mybuttonid1') {
                var txtid = '#mytextid1’;
            } else if ( btnid == '#mybuttonid2') {
                var txtid = '#mytextid2’;
            } else if ( btnid == '#mybuttonid3') {
                var txtid = '#mytextid3’;
            } else {
                var txtid = '#htxmltiimgupdtlw';
            }

            // Grabs the attachment selection and creates a JSON representation of the model.
            var media_attachment = meta_image_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();

            // Sends the attachment URL to our custom image input field.
            $( txtid ).val(media_attachment.url);
        });

        // Opens the media library frame.
        meta_image_frame.open();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Amin, but it still doesn't work. I also tried these offshoots (opening code only examples), no luck:

`$.each( btnid, function(){
$(this.value).click(function(e) {

$.each( btnid, function(value){
$(this.value).click(function(e) {`

Also tried changing how array is setup:

`var btnid = [ '#mybuttonid1', '#mybuttonid2', 'mybuttonid3', 'mybuttonid4' ];`

The button function isn't opening the meta_image_frame DOM. Again, when I use a single var as the element, works fine.

Comment: I was thinking of taking a slightly different approach, since .each() isn't working. What if I make the button selector a general ID, so any button with a particular .class would be the selector, then extract attr(ID) and then my if statements work, for example:

`var btnid = $(':button.myClass').attr('id');`

The button would need to have a .class otherwise every button input on the page would open the WP image uploader. I know my syntax is still wrong, but is this possible. If so, how would it actually be coded? Thanks again!